# cURL error 60: SSL certificate : self signed certificate in certificate chain (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Tags: laravel-5.3

I try to setwebhook my code is :

```
public function setWebHook() {
 $telegram = new Api('290420684:AAHTAL4tCx9Jm01e6brv8V4St5WnlbAP4Dg'); 
$resp = Telegram::setWebHook([ 'url' => 'https://https://ab702b21.ngrok.io/api/webhook/AAHTAL4tCx9Jm01e6brv8V4St5WnlbAP4Dg'    
    ]);
    var_dump($resp);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is probably stale CA certificates store your PHP installation using. Try following:

1. Download fresh [CA certs file](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem).
2. Configure your php.ini to use it `curl.cainfo=/path/you/placed/cacert.pem`.